# Do async calls in services block component load in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The angularjs [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) contains an example detailing an async call in a service.
The following code is given

```
angular.module('finance3', [])
.factory('currencyConverter', ['$http', function($http) {
  var currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY'];
  var usdToForeignRates = {};

  var convert = function(amount, inCurr, outCurr) {
    return amount * usdToForeignRates[outCurr] / usdToForeignRates[inCurr];
  };

  var refresh = function() {
    var url = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=' + currencies.join(",");
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
      usdToForeignRates = response.data.rates;
      usdToForeignRates['USD'] = 1;
    });
  };

  refresh();

  return {
    currencies: currencies,
    convert: convert
  };
}]);
```

Since the `refresh` function is async, how does angularjs ensure that the data is loaded before loading the controller which accesses the data returned by the `refresh` function, ie the data contained in the `usdToForeignRates` object.
I assume there is some blocking going on somewhere, otherwise when the controller accesses the object returned, it will get undefined values.

I want to understand the flow, does angular internally ensure that service loads before injecting it into the controller?

Comment: *"how does angularjs ensure that the data is loaded before loading the controller"* — It doesn't.

Comment: @deceze Is the example wrong then?

Comment: As far as I can see, it doesn't ensure the data is available before the controller is loaded, so you _could_ try to convert before the data is available. In practice the data probably will be available before the user is interacting with the UI, but there's no guarantee for that. The example is probably too simplistic really. It doesn't really contain any explanation either, so the author probably just filled it in as a footnote.